# Android interstitial ad seems to block AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, interstitial

I have two activities (Activity A and B) and when user moves from the Activity A to Activity B my app displays Intersitial Ad. In the Activity B app has AsyncTask which gets data from database using Room.

Evertything works fine when Activity B starts without any Ads or Ads with no time counter. If Interstital Ad has a time counter and after it finishes and Activity B starts seems no data get from AsyncTask.

So it should be as in the picture 3, but in fact it is as in the Picture 2.
[image]

**Activity A**

```
        if (id == R.id.menuCalendar) {

            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                        // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                        // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                        // show it a second time.
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });
                mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CalendarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

          return true;
        }
```

**Activity B**

```
mCalendarViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(CalendarViewModel.class);
mCalendarViewModel.getTodoListForMonth(new CalendarParams(year, month)).observe(this, new Observer<List<TODO>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<TODO> todos) {
        DisplayCalendarInfo(todos);
    }
});
mCalendarViewModel.setDateFilter(new CalendarParams(year, month));
```

Comment: How about some code, when do you instantiate and run the ASyncTask that's not working when there is an ad?

Comment: I will try to follow @logancodemaker advise

Comment: yes but.... LiveData isn't quite a replacement for an AsyncTask. Yes, you should use it, but it might not have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: @Shark, you are right. This replacement did not solve my problem. Moreover, I have noticed sometimes everything works like a charm inspite of any type of ads. This looks very weird. I added some piece of code.

Comment: [mcve] please, as it is this is a "whats wrong with my code, btw i'm not posting the code" type of question.

Answer (score -2):

Stop using AsyncTask, use LiveData instead.AsyncTask has been deprecated for a very long time.

[Read this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries) to know how to handle asynchronous queries with Room